# Hash code generator in Java

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm looking for a hash code generator that will generate a unique hash from these characters: [a-zA-Z0-9] and that generates two-character hash like: `aZ` or `g2`

That is less likely to collide; with Java.

Comment: You want to hash a single character into a two-character hash? You could just take the identity, `h(c) = { 0, c }` or something like that.

Comment: A hash is usually not unique. And if you had a unique hash/ID, then there'd be no chance of a collision. Could you explain a bit more? You say your words will be only of chars `[a-zA-Z0-9]` but surely the words have a max number of characters?

Comment: do you want the hash to be [a-zA-Z0-9], or you want to hash a char in that range?

Comment: what should be in that range. The hash, or the input

Comment: @Bozho the hash should be in that range. I am actually thinking if this would scale up to large sets or the hash will just be limited. As rossum advised in his answer.

Comment: considering that only two characters will be used as output hash.

Comment: So, what do you want to hash then? Any object? Any string? Try to be more precise.

Comment: Its a variable length string. A long string perhaps. However, my idea is just to create a unique key (I may be wrong that I asked for hash)

Comment: I will need to store a key or a hash (if its possible to hash into two-character length) into a database, so its like a key-value store.

Comment: BTW: You have over 30 questions without an accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest approach is to multiply by 127 (The smallest prime larger than 'Z' => 122)  This will be unique for all Strings up to 4 characters long and do a decent job for longer strings. i.e. for every string up to 4 characters you can encode and decode the string and get the original.  If you want longer unique ids, you could use a `long` which can encode up to 9 characters uniquely this way.

---

A simple solution

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    for (String s : "A,a,aa,AA,a1,A1,ABCD,1234,'hi bye'".split(",")) {
        long l = hashFor(s);
        String s2 = decode(l);
        System.out.printf("Hashcode for %s is %d, decoded is %s%n", s, l, s2);
    }
}

public static long hashFor(String s) {
    long l = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
        l = l * 127 + s.charAt(i);
    return l & Long.MAX_VALUE; // stay positive
}

public static String decode(long l) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(9);
    while (l > 0) {
        sb.append((char) (l % 127));
        l /= 127;
    }
    return sb.reverse().toString();
}
```

prints

```
Hashcode for A is 65, decoded is A
Hashcode for a is 97, decoded is a
Hashcode for aa is 12416, decoded is aa
Hashcode for AA is 8320, decoded is AA
Hashcode for a1 is 12368, decoded is a1
Hashcode for A1 is 8304, decoded is A1
Hashcode for ABCD is 134217986, decoded is ABCD
Hashcode for 1234 is 101183746, decoded is 1234
Hashcode for 'hi bye' is 21222006885704529, decoded is 'hi bye'
```

Comment: Can you site some example resource for this solution on the web?

Comment: Its pretty simple to write for yourself based on the `String.hashCode()` using 127 instead of 31 as the constant.

Comment: cool thanks. However, is it possible to 'clip' the hash to say always 4 characters long? It seems that the hash generated by the code above generates arbitrary length based on input?

Comment: You can decide to give the hash() strings of no more than four characters.  You might like to cast the result to `int` or change hash to only use `int`

Answer (score 2):

The representation of the hash should not matter. It is a number / array of bytes, and you can then transform it to whatever you like. Base64, Hex, etc. Base64 lets you use the least number of characters in ISO-8859-1. Also note that you can't have a good hash of only two ascii symbols. It will cause collisions.

Comment: Base64 includes 2 characters ('+' and '/') that are not wanted.  Base62 is what is required.

Comment: perhaps I've misunderstood the question. I assumed he wants a hash of a char, and then the representation might be anything

Comment: It looks like that Bozho is right, its hard to hash with just two ascii. Four would be the best while keeping the character count low?

Answer (score 1):

Your [a-zA-Z0-9] is 62 characters.  Hence your final hash is a 2 'digit' base 62 number.  Calculate a normal Java integer hash.  Mod it with (62^2) and convert the result to base 62.